# Unit-testing a directive with isolated scope, bidirectional value and ngIf

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

I want to unit test a directive which looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('myTest', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { message: '='},
        replace: true,
        template:  '<div ng-if="message"><p>{{message}}</p></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        }
    };
});
```

Here is my failing test:

```
describe('myTest directive:', function () {

    var scope, compile, validHTML;

    validHTML = '<my-test message="message"></my-test>';

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope){
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        compile = $compile;
    }));

    function create() {
        var elem, compiledElem;
        elem = angular.element(validHTML);
        compiledElem = compile(elem)(scope);
        scope.$digest();

        return compiledElem;    
    }

    it('should have a scope on root element', function () {  
        scope.message = 'not empty';
        var el = create();
        console.log(el.text());
        expect(el.text()).toBeDefined();
        expect(el.text()).not.toBe('');
    });

});
```

Can you spot why it's failing?

The corresponding [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unludo/gczT3/1/)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 console.log((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(el.get(0)));
```

returns

```
 <!-- ngIf: message -->
```

because you are using replace without a parent element in validHTML with combinaison of ng-if .So either you change validHTML and add a div as parent.

or

test your expectations on the next sibling of el

```
el.next()
```

which will be

```
<div ng-if="message" message="message" class="ng-scope"><p class="ng-binding">yes</p></div>
```

Comment: It's working thx. Here is the updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/unludo/gczT3/2/

Comment: Do you know why a comment element is created when there is no parent?